# How could a regex look like which, for a name-surname pattern, prevents name shortening to just two separated but single characters?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I've been checking strings with this regex until now.

`^[a-zA-ZöÖşŞçÇüÜıİğĞ.]{1,}(?:\s{1}[a-zA-ZöÖşŞçÇüÜıİğĞ.]{1,})+$`

This is a regex that allows the following examples.

- Robert Downey
- R. Downey
- Robert D.

But I want prevent both word from being single charackter like this.

- R D
- R. D.

I want name surname like below

- R Downey => This is ok.
- Robert D=> This is ok.
- R. Downey=> This is ok.
- Robert D.=> This is ok.
- R D => This is NOT ok.
- R. D. => This is NOT ok.

How can I handle it?

Comment: @muhammedozer ... From all the provided answers(approaches, are there any questions left? And in order to show appreciation for any of the helpers effort the OP might think about flagging the to the OP most helpful answer (there is a button/link to press).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a positive lookahead at the start of the regex asserting that at least one two letter (or more) name component appears, somewhere:

```js
var names = ["R Downey", "Robert D", "R. Downey", "Robert D.", "R D", "R. D."];
for (var i=0; i < names.length; ++i) {
    var result = /^(?=.*[a-zA-ZöÖşŞçÇüÜıİğĞ]{2})[a-zA-ZöÖşŞçÇüÜıİğĞ.]{1,}(?:\s{1}[a-zA-ZöÖşŞçÇüÜıİğĞ.]{1,})+$/.test(names[i]);
    console.log(names[i] + " => " + result);
}
```

For an explanation of the regex pattern used above, I have only added the following positive lookahead to the very start of the pattern:

```regex
(?=.*[a-zA-ZöÖşŞçÇüÜıİğĞ]{2})
```

This asserts that we can find, somewhere in the full name, a two character word.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a good idea to take a look at [negative lookahead](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind), this could let you find cases like `R. D` using i.e. `(?![a-zA-ZöÖşŞçÇüÜıİğĞ.]\.)`

Comment: Note that the pattern `(?![a-zA-ZöÖşŞçÇüÜıİğĞ.]\.)` by itself does not make sure that there are at least 2 chars out of the character class `[a-zA-ZöÖşŞçÇüÜıİğĞ]`

Answer (score 1):

Alternative regex:

```
/^(?:[a-zA-ZöÖşŞçÇüÜıİğĞ]{1,}\.?\s[a-zA-ZöÖşŞçÇüÜıİğĞ]{2,}|[a-zA-ZöÖşŞçÇüÜıİğĞ]{2,}\s[a-zA-ZöÖşŞçÇüÜıİğĞ]{1,}\.?)/
```

Regex in testbench and context:

```
const names = ["R Downey", "Robert D", "R. Downey", "Robert D.", "R D", "R. D."];

const regex = /^(?:[a-zA-ZöÖşŞçÇüÜıİğĞ]{1,}\.?\s[a-zA-ZöÖşŞçÇüÜıİğĞ]{2,}|[a-zA-ZöÖşŞçÇüÜıİğĞ]{2,}\s[a-zA-ZöÖşŞçÇüÜıİğĞ]{1,}\.?)/;

names.forEach(myFunction);

function myFunction(name) {
    console.log(name + " => " + regex.test(name));
}
```

Output:

```
R Downey => true
Robert D => true
R. Downey => true
Robert D. => true
R D => false
R. D. => false
```

Answer (score 1):

- basic latin `\w` word character and `\s` whitespace and `\.` dot.

  - [`/(?:\w{2,}\s+\w{2,})|(?:\w\.?\s+\w{2,})|(?:\w{2,}\s+\w\.?)/`](https://regex101.com/r/ALarkU/1)

... making use of [Unicode property escapes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) ...

- unicode `\p{L}` letter and unicode `\p{Z}` whitespace and `\.` dot.

  - [`/(?:\p{L}{2,}\p{Z}+\p{L}{2,})|(?:\p{L}\.?\p{Z}+\p{L}{2,})|(?:\p{L}{2,}\p{Z}+\p{L}\.?)/u`](https://regex101.com/r/ALarkU/2)

All the above patterns describe 3 possible name occurrences

- either ... `\w{2,}\s+\w{2,})` => ***full name*** ...

  - at least two word characters
  - followed by at least one whitespace character
  - followed by at least two word characters.
- or ... `(?:\w\.?\s+\w{2,})` => ***shortened 1st name and full 2nd name*** ...

  - a single word character
  - followed by none or one dot
  - followed by at least one whitespace character
  - followed by at least two word characters.
- or ... `(?:\w{2,}\s+\w\.?)` => ***full 1st name and shortened 2nd name*** ...

  - at least two word characters
  - followed by at least one whitespace character
  - followed by a single word character
  - followed by none or one dot.

```js
const samples = [
  'Robert Downey',  // => This is ok.
  'Robert D',       // => This is ok.
  'R. Downey',      // => This is ok.
  'R Downey',       // => This is ok.
  'Robert D.',      // => This is ok.
  'R D',            // => This is NOT ok.
  'R. D.',          // => This is NOT ok.
];

// [https://regex101.com/r/ALarkU/1]
// basic latin \w word character and \s whitespace and \. dot.
const regXNonFullyShortenedLat = (/(?:\w{2,}\s+\w{2,})|(?:\w\.?\s+\w{2,})|(?:\w{2,}\s+\w\.?)/);

// [https://regex101.com/r/ALarkU/2]
// unicode \p{L} letter and unicode \p{Z} whitespace and \. dot.
const regXNonFullyShortenedUni = (/(?:\p{L}{2,}\p{Z}+\p{L}{2,})|(?:\p{L}\.?\p{Z}+\p{L}{2,})|(?:\p{L}{2,}\p{Z}+\p{L}\.?)/u);

console.log(
  'basic latin \\w word character and \\s whitespace and \\. dot ...',
  samples.map(name =>
    `${ name } => This is ${ !regXNonFullyShortenedLat.test(name) ? 'NOT ' : ''}ok.` 
  )
);
console.log(
  'unicode \\p{L} letter and unicode \\p{Z} whitespace and \\. dot ...',
  samples.map(name =>
    `${ name } => This is ${ !regXNonFullyShortenedUni.test(name) ? 'NOT ' : ''}ok.` 
  )
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Of cause one can, instead of writing pattern variations like above, make use of something like [*look-arounds*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). If such an approach is more readable, easier to comprehend or better consumed by the regex-engine I personally can not tell.

But here it is ... [`(?:(?:^\w\.?\s+)(?=\w\w)\w+)|(?:^\w{2,}\s\w+\.?)`](https://regex101.com/r/ALarkU/3) ... and the explanation is as follows ...

One does start with a simple matching of one of the allowed variants ... e.g. [`(?:^\w\.?\s+)`](https://regex101.com/r/ALarkU/5)

- at the beginning of a line
- match a single word character
- which is followed by a single or none dot
- followed by at least one whitespace

... **but only if** ... and here one adds the positive lookahead ... [`(?:^\w\.?\s+)(?=\w\w)\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/ALarkU/6)

- all of the before is followed by two word characters
- Then one safely matches all following word characters.

... and still one needs to go for the rest ... [`(?:(?:^\w\.?\s+)(?=\w\w)\w+)|(?:^\w{2,}\s\w+\.?)`](https://regex101.com/r/ALarkU/7) ... thus one does provide via or/`|` yet an additional alternative pattern `(?:^\w{2,}\s\w+\.?)` ...

- at the beginning of a line
- match at least two word characters
- followed by at least one whitespace
- followed by at least one word character
- followed by a single or none dot.

The following example code does additionally provide the *unicode escapes* variant of the above described pattern.

```js
const samples = [
  'Robert Downey',  // => This is ok.
  'Robert D',       // => This is ok.
  'R. Downey',      // => This is ok.
  'R Downey',       // => This is ok.
  'Robert D.',      // => This is ok.
  'R D',            // => This is NOT ok.
  'R. D.',          // => This is NOT ok.
];

// [https://regex101.com/r/ALarkU/3]
// positive lookahed and basic latin \w word character and \s whitespace and \. dot.
const regXNonFullyShortenedLat = (/(?:(?:^\w\.?\s+)(?=\w\w)\w+)|(?:^\w{2,}\s\w+\.?)/);

// [https://regex101.com/r/ALarkU/4]
// positive lookahed and unicode \p{L} letter and unicode \p{Z} whitespace and \. dot.
const regXNonFullyShortenedUni = (/(?:(?:^\p{L}\.?\p{Z}+)(?=\p{L}\p{L})\p{L}+)|(?:^\p{L}{2,}\p{Z}\p{L}+\.?)/u);

console.log(
  'positive lookahed and basic latin \\w word character and \\s whitespace and \\. dot ...',
  samples.map(name =>
    `${ name } => This is ${ !regXNonFullyShortenedLat.test(name) ? 'NOT ' : ''}ok.` 
  )
);
console.log(
  'positive lookahed and unicode \\p{L} letter and unicode \\p{Z} whitespace and \\. dot ...',
  samples.map(name =>
    `${ name } => This is ${ !regXNonFullyShortenedUni.test(name) ? 'NOT ' : ''}ok.` 
  )
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```